# OpenSSL Can't open cert_config.txt for reading, No such file or directory 25968:error:02001002:system library:fopen:

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, aws-iot

I am in step 3 of AWS OTA documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/ota-code-sign-cert-esp.html

I am able to do the first two steps but not able to make the certificate:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -config cert_config.txt -extensions my_exts -nodes -days 365 -key ecdsasigner.key -out ecdsasigner.crt
```

I get the following error:

> Can't open cert_config.txt for reading, No such file or directory
>
> 25968:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('cert_config.txt','r')
>
> 25968:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:

I have tried:

1. installing another version of ssl instead of using git bash but I ran into the same issue
2. I have tried elevated privleges as adminstrator
3. I have tried the full path to "cert_config.txt" with or without double quotations and to no avail

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I am an idiot, if I look at the full file it's cert_config.txt.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am an idiot, if I look at the full file it's cert_config.txt.txt

Comment: If this solves your problem, mark your own answer as "accepted answer"

Answer (score 0):

Try ./cert_config.txt in the parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, same error arises